# Стародавние времена

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Грамотно ли выражение "стародавние времена"? Если давние, то уже старые, по-моему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это действительно устоявшееся слово. **Сочетанием** я бы называть поостерёгся, "стародавними" могут быть не только времена, но еще много чего: обычаи, идеи, просто люди. 
Но дело не в этом. "Стародавние" - действительно тавтология (в широком смыле), но не всякая такая тавтология зло, здесь она очень даже удачная. Слово само по себе отсылает к той архаичной (стародавней!) речи, где такие повторы-рефрены были в порядке вещей.

Answer (score 1):

*"Стародавние времена"* — уже устоявшееся выражение, поэтому оно вполне грамотное. Я думаю, что в одно слово соединили два синонимичных корня с целью усиления значения.